# Error while deploying cruisecontrol.war in jboss 6

Tags: jboss6.x

I tried deploying `cruisecontrol.war` in `jboss6`. But it is shown deploying error like this.:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "net.sf.saxon.pull.PullToStax.getNamespaceContext()Ljavax/xml/namespace/Names
paceContext;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, net/sf/saxon/pull/PullToStax, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext used in the signature
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with classloading, please check if you have a conflict between the jar/war in the JBoss and jar in your classpath.